# How to copy specific attribute using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Apologies for the basic nature of these questions - I'm brand new to XSLT (and to Stack Overflow too).

I need to transform the following XML being returned by a Sharepoint Web service:

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns=
   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
   <Groups>
      <Group ID="3" Name="Group1" Description="Description" OwnerID="1" 
         OwnerIsUser="False" />
      <Group ID="15" Name="Group2" Description="Description" 
         OwnerID="12" OwnerIsUser="True" />
      <Group ID="16" Name="Group3" Description="Description" 
         OwnerID="7" OwnerIsUser="False" />
   </Groups>
</GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

into this:

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns=
   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
   <Groups>
      <Group Name="Group1" />
      <Group Name="Group2" />
      <Group Name="Group3" />
   </Groups>
</GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

Basically, I need to drop all the attributes for each Group element except Name. After a lot of research and tinkering, and notably dropping the namespace declaration from the original XML, I've come up with something that gets me almost exactly what I need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/GetGroupCollectionFromUser">
    <xsl:copy>                  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Groups" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Groups">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Group" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@Name" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, instead of a Name attribute, the above gives me the value of the Name attribute inserted as text into the Group element, like so:

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
    <Groups>
        <Group>Group1</Group>
        <Group>Group2</Group>
        <Group>Group3</Group>
    </Groups>
</GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

This will ultimately be consumed by a third-party application that's expecting attribute-centric XML. I'm sure I'm missing something embarrassingly obvious, but no matter what I do with it I can't seem to pull in just the Name attribute. Two questions:

How do I alter the XSLT to return a Name attribute for each Group element, instead of its value as text?

And, how do I handle the namespace properly? When I've included it in the XSLT, trying several methods based on examples I've found here and elsewhere on the web, I get nothing at all back.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is possibly one of the shortest transformations that correctly produces the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*[not(name()='Name')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns=
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
    <Groups>
        <Group ID="3" Name="Group1" Description="Description" OwnerID="1"           OwnerIsUser="False" />
        <Group ID="15" Name="Group2" Description="Description"           OwnerID="12" OwnerIsUser="True" />
        <Group ID="16" Name="Group3" Description="Description"           OwnerID="7" OwnerIsUser="False" />
    </Groups>
</GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
   <Groups>
      <Group Name="Group1"/>
      <Group Name="Group2"/>
      <Group Name="Group3"/>
   </Groups>
</GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule (template) copies every node "as-is".**
2. **There is just one template that overrides the identity rule**. It matches any attribute whose name is not "Name". The body of the template is empty and this results in any matched attribute not copied.

**Using and overriding the identity rule is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. Read about it [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: Thanks very much! And for the identity reference, that's going to come in handy. Am I correct in assuming that node()|@* is returning all nodes plus all attributes? And I read @*[not(name()='Name')] as "get all attributes not having the name Name," yet it actually does the opposite? Again, apologies for the basic questions.

Comment: @rlg: `node()|@*` is an XPath expression (in this case a match pattern). It *selects* any `child::node()` or any `attribute::*` of the current node. This means: all attributes and all element, text-nodes, processing instruction and comment nodes -- children.

Comment: @rlg: `@*[not(name()='Name')] ` selects any attribute, whose name is not "Name". This means that the template having this match-pattern is selected to process all such attributes. The processing is null -- so they are not copied to the output.

Answer (score 3):

The way to handle these situations is by overriding the Identity Transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msft="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="msft:Group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Name" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
    <Groups>
        <Group Name="Group1" />
        <Group Name="Group2" />
        <Group Name="Group3" />
    </Groups>
</GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

Note that the output is properly namespaced.

This solution is preferred because of its simplicity and flexibility. All nodes and attributes are copied as-is, unless an override exists that specifies an alternate behavior.

Comment: +1 It looks very powerfull (esoteric to me), but giving it a try it copies all the attributes in the output. Where `msft` is coming from?

Comment: The source XML specifies a namespace: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"`. This needs to be accounted for in the XSLT. See the `stylesheet` element for how to assign a name -- in this case `msft` -- to the namespace found in the source doc, so that you can properly refer to the element later.

Comment: ok, but in your solution all the attributes are still copied to the output.

Comment: @empo - No, they're not. Are you using the OP's *exact* input and my *exact* stylesheet? My guess is you're not accounting for namespaces.

Comment: @empo - Note that I decided to update to use `xsl:copy`, but, either way, this does not output all attributes.

Comment: @lwburk: You may be interested to see a shorter solution than yours that is completely push-style.

Comment: Thanks lwburk - this worked for me in my testing tool - my third-party app doesn't interpret it correctly but I have no way to know what it's using as an XSLT engine. Had to go with Dimitre's example ultimately but yours helped too, much appreciated.

Comment: @Dimitre - Your solution is shorter, but less resilient to change. What if someone comes along and adds a new element under the root with a `Name` attribute, or simply adds a `Name` attribute to the `Groups` element? It would be removed. Of course, only the OP can say whether that's the expected result, but I think many would find it unexpected. There is a tension between the solution that makes only the desired, localized changes, and a shorter solution that generalizes.

Comment: @lwburk: The next step to make a solution more resilient to change is to take into account the weather... :) More seriously, you are right that we don't know the OP's context, that is why answering the question strictly is more reasonable.

Comment: @lwburk: No, if a `Name` attribute is added anywhere, it *will* be copied.

Comment: @Dimitre - Oops. I said it backwards. Of course I meant it *would* be copied, but others would be removed. I don't really feel strongly about this, anyway. Each answer produces the same output for *this exact input*, but has differing behavior for modified input. I can't predict the future, but sometimes it's fun to try :)

Comment: @Dimitre - A common example of predicting the future is providing the correct identity transform when someone asks how to copy a document that happens to contain no attributes or processing instructions or whatever. You *could* just provide a template that copies only elements and it *would* produce their desired output *on that document*. But it's reasonable to guess that attributes might be added later and that they'd probably be surprised when they didn't copy.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it becomes easier for you if you don't use `xsl:copy` here. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="Groups/*">
 <xsl:element name="Group">
     <xsl:attribute name="Name">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
     </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Answer to second question is a [FAQ](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200010/post60200.html). Declare the namespace and use the declared prefix in your xsl. Final solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:myns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/director/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:template match="/myns:GetGroupCollectionFromUser">
  <Groups>                 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="myns:Groups" />
  </Groups>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="myns:Groups/*">
  <xsl:element name="Group">
     <xsl:attribute name="Name">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
     </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This only returns the last group for me, though I admit I don't know too much xslt so I might be missing something. I'm testing using http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Comment: Ops, I blame myself...now you have the simplest solution.

Comment: @empo - Your first template does not match any elements in the source document due to not respecting namespaces. Your complete stylesheet example does not produce the requested output.

Comment: @Iwburk: I was just giving hints, that's not so nice and ambiguous, true. You have the complete solution now.

Comment: This is unnecessarily long and convoluted. Also, incorrect, because it loses the default namespace.

Comment: @Dimitre: I like your expression _convoluted_. Sorry for not being the master of **XSLT**.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
<xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Completely incorrect: Notice the default namespace. Also, the output loses the top element.

Comment: @Dimitre - This isn't a whole solution - It is based on the OP's solution, replacing only the Group template.

Comment: This template doesn't match any node -- due to the default namespace. No way this could produce a non-empty result. You have not even tested and verified that your proposed solution really produces the wanted result.

Comment: @Dimitre - That is unfair. I actually did test it. It is working without the namespace (as the OP said his/her works "After [...] dropping the namespace declaration from the original XML"), though that isn't optimal as well.

Comment: The OP said that he couldn't make his transformation work in the case of the default namespace -- not that he wanted a solution without namespace.